# How would I join this query in one single SQL statement?

Tags: sql, mysql

Let's say I have these tables, with these fields:

**companies**: company_id | name | num_employees

**companies_countries**: company_id | country_id

**countries**: country_id | country_iso_code

Assuming this is a 1:1 relationship:
How can I join the country_iso_code directly into the company recordset, when I fetch all the companies? I think I would need two joins here?

Comment: LEFT JOIN countries to companies_countries which is in turn left joined to companies. 
Daniel Vassallo and Arthur Thomas have the best answers in my opinion.
I suggest LEFT JOINs in case there is missing data in the companies_countries or countries tables, unless that isn't an issue (or you can guarantee correct data), in which case use INNER JOIN.
Don't use WHERE cross-product type joins. Large datasets can cause excessive (unwanted) processing.
I also recommend reading up more about different types of SQL joins - essential and valuable knowledge for database programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple example :

```
select c.name, n.country_iso_code
from companies c,
companies_countries x,
countries n
where x.company_id = c.company_id
and n.country_id = x.country_id
```

### Edit

For a good intro to JOIN, have a look at [SQL JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Comment: I learned SQL in the 80s, this is the original form of 'join' syntax, which to me is easier to read and takes less words to write

Comment: But internally it's the same thing as if I would use JOIN keywords?

Comment: The implicit join in the sql example I gave is equivalent to specifying an INNER JOIN. Have a squizz at the link in my edited answer.

Comment: It is not generally exactly equivalent - or rather, it is only equivalent in absence of JOIN conditions in the ON clause. From the manual: 

    INNER JOIN and ,  (comma) are semantically equivalent in the absence of a join condition: both produce a Cartesian product between the specified tables (that is, each and every row in the first table is joined to each and every row in the second table).  You probably want a LEFT JOIN anyway.

Comment: @mst : I don't think you understand the fine points : maybe you should have a look at the link in my answer too.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
    companies.company_id, 
    companies.name, 
    companies.num_employees, 
    countries.country_iso_code
FROM
    companies
LEFT JOIN
    companies_countries ON (companies_countries.company_id = companies.company_id)
LEFT JOIN
    countries ON (countries.country_id = companies_countries.country_id);
```

A query that uses a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN` or an implicit join, will return companies even when they have no country assigned. On the other hand, a query with an `INNER JOIN` would skip companies that do not have an assigned country in `companies_countries`.

Note that your design is implying that each company can be assigned more than one country. If you want to enforce only one country for each company, simply put a `country_id` column in your `companies` table. You would not need the `companies_countries` table.

Comment: Thanks. Sure that would be easier. I try to maintain flexibility with this, so at any given time in future I could turn the switch and say: "hey, now this is an 1:n relationship, my friends!", and users can start add more than one photo to their profile (for example), without restructuring the database.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT co.*, cu.country_iso_code 
FROM companies co 
LEFT JOIN companies_countries cc ON cc.company_id = co.company_id
LEFT JOIN countries c ON c.country_id = cc.country_id
```

Why LEFT JOIN and not the WHERE condition like in other examples? A join table (companies_countries) is not typically used in 1:1 relationships - it is overnormalization.

When your relationship ceases to be 1:1:

```
SELECT co.*, GROUP_CONCAT(cu.country_iso_code)
FROM companies co 
LEFT JOIN companies_countries cc ON cc.company_id = co.company_id
LEFT JOIN countries c ON c.country_id = cc.country_id
```

This will return results like

```
CompanyA | Canada,USA,Mexico
CompanyB | Ireland,UK,Japan
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select name, country_iso_code 
from companies left join companies_countries 
   on (companies.company_id = companies_countries.company_id)
left join countries 
   on (companies_countries.country_id = countries.country_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a `1:1` relationship. A country can have more the one company.

This is either a `1:N` relationship (for some reason implemented using two relational tables), or the `M:N` relationship which describes multinational companies.

If this is a `1:N` relationship, you could just put the `country_code` field into the `companies` table, in which case one join would be enough:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    companies co
LEFT JOIN
        countries cn
ON      cn.country_code = co.country_code
```

Your design is viable for both `1:N` and `M:N` relationships, in which case two joins are required:

```
SELECT  co.*, cn.*
FROM    companies co
LEFT JOIN
        company_countries cc
ON      cc.company_id = co.company_id
LEFT JOIN
        countries cn
ON      cn.country_code = cc.country_code
```

If this is a `1:N` relationship, you should make `company_id` a `PRIMARY KEY` in the `company_country` table.

If this is a `M:N` relationship, you should make a composite `PRIMARY KEY` on `company_country (company_id, country_code)`

You may want to read this article in my blog about the difference between entity-relationship model and its relational implementation:

- [**What is entity-relationship model?**](http://explainextended.com/2009/10/18/what-is-entity-relationship-model/)

Comment: Your blog article is great. Have commented it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need two joins.

You can create a view and **fake** a single join though...

Comment: There are advantages and disadvantages with a view. Pro: the view will serve as a central definition of the read part of the 1:1 relationship. You will be able to update it centrally when the 1:1 relationship is no longer relevant. Cons: weaker performance (under MySQL anyway - PostgreSQL has the awesome rule tree rewriter which actually makes Postgres views behave more like macros and not stored queries)

Answer (score 1):

```
select companies.* from countries, companies_countries, companies where countries.country_id=companies_countries and companies_countries.company_id=company_id and countries.country_iso_code='xxxx'
```

where xxxx is the iso code you want to match

Comment: is that essentially the same thing as using "join" keywords? I see you write from a,b,c, so I assume this is another syntax for joining? Is there a difference in performance?

Comment: `@openfrog`: this is a such called implicit join syntax, as opposed to `ANSI`, or explicit join syntax (which used the `JOIN` keywords). In all databases I'm aware of both syntaxes use the same execution plans, but the `ANSI` syntax is generally considered more legible.

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.company_id, c.name, c.num_employees, co.county_iso_code from
companies c, companies_countries cc, countries co
where c.company_id = cc.company_id 
and cc.country_id = co.country_id
```